# User defined input in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a script that reads .csv files and I want to set it up so it can be run as follows

```
python script.py file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv
```

I would also like the output of the script (which is a .csv) to name the csv's based on the input.

Here are the current lines

```
with open("test2.csv","wb") as f:
    output = csv.writer(f) 
    for line in csv.reader(open("test.csv")):
```

I have tried using raw_input but it doesnt seem to be appropriate for the job, is there another way?

Comment: So what are your questions acutally? You need help with setting up your Python script to accept 3 CSVs as arguments and setting you output file's filename to some user input?

Comment: Just new to programming/python and wanted to know if there was a better way to do things than raw_input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use [sys.argv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv), or for more easy and sophisticated parsing the [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html)
standard library.

An example would be:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("infile")
parser.add_argument("outfile")
args = parser.parse_args()

with open(args.outfile, "wb") as f:
    output = cvs.writer(f)
    for line in csv.reader(open(args.infile)):
```

For more sophisticated examples, such as accepting a variable amount of input files and exactly one output file, please see the argparse documentation linked above or the [argparse tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html#id1).

Comment: Something like `ap.add_argument('files', metavar='CSV', type=str, nargs='+', help='data file')` could be useful in OP's case, to make it completle effortless for him =)

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following to your script:

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

And running:

```
python script.py file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv
```

You will get the following output:

```
['script.py', 'file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv']
```

I.e., sys.argv contains a list, whose first item is the name of the script being run, and whose subsequent items are the options / filenames being passed.